# Percent of a percent

Tags: percentages

I'm trying to calculate the correct percentages of both red and blue paint from a starting mix... It's difficult for me to explain, but the example should be easy enough...

Let's say I have the following recipe:

```
Starting Mix: 22.20% (already mixed at 90% Red, 10% Blue)

Added Red: ??%
Added Blue: ??%

Extras: 9% (These stay as they are, without any Red or Blue)
```

The starting mix has 90% Red in it, 10% Blue in it, and at the end I want 60% Red and 40% Blue in the whole mix (excluding the "Extras"), so I want 60% Red in the total of 91%, and 40% Blue in the total of 91%.

How do I calculate the Added Blue and Added Red percentages for this? Is there a simple formula I can follow, as the starting mix may change, for example 100% Red, and the output may be different (for example 20% Red, 80% Blue).

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** This is not a homework question, it's actually to help me work out e-liquid PG/VG splits when making my own vape juices, but I simplified the question to "paint" to try to make it easier to understand.

Comment: What is the $22.20\%$ in the first line? To make this clearer, perhaps you could assume you have 100 gallons and tell us how much of each ingredient you have at the start and at the end (and, if you do that, I suspect you may answer your own question).

Comment: Sorry my bad, 22.20% is the total percentage of the starting mix. So 22.20% + 9% + 68.80% (the "added" red and blue) = 100% of the total mixture. Out of the 68.80%, I need to know what percentage of that needs to be Red, and what needs to be Blue to end up with 60% Red and 40% Blue of the Starting Mix + Added Mixtures (don't include the Extras)

Answer (score 2):

This is the balance for a volume $V_1$ of 90-10 mix and a volume $V_2$ of 60-40 mix.

$$
\frac{V_1}{9+1} 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
9 \\ 
1
\end{matrix}
\right] + V_r 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 \\ 
0
\end{matrix}
\right] + V_b 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 \\ 
1
\end{matrix}
\right] = 
\frac{V_2}{6 + 4}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
6 \\ 
4
\end{matrix}
\right] \\
$$

Here we can solve for the parts $V_r$ of red paint and $V_b$ of blue paint.

$$
\begin{align}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
V_r \\ 
V_b
\end{matrix}
\right] &= \frac{V_2}{6 + 4} 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
6 \\ 
4
\end{matrix}
\right] - \frac{V_1}{9+1}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
9 \\ 
1
\end{matrix}
\right] \\
&= \left[
\begin{matrix}
\frac{6}{10} V_2 - \frac{9}{10} V_1 \\ 
\frac{4}{10} V_2 - \frac{1}{10} V_1
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{align}
$$

Relative to $V_2$, we have 
$$
\begin{align}
p_r &= \frac{V_r}{V_2} \cdot 100 \, \% 
= 60 \% - 90 \% \cdot \frac{V_1}{V_2} \\
p_b &= \frac{V_b}{V_2} \cdot 100 \, \%
= 40 \% - 10 \% \cdot \frac{V_1}{V_2}
\end{align}
$$

Note:

$$
V_r + V_b = V_2 - V_1
$$
like it should be. And to get positive parts the condition
$$
\frac{V_1}{V_2} \le \frac{2}{3} = 0.\bar{6}
$$
must hold.

Example:

$V_1 = 100$, $V_2 = 200$ of whatever volume units, then we need to add
$V_r = 30$ and $V_b = 70$ volume units.

The percentages are: $p_r = 15 \%$ and $p_b = 35 \%$ of $V_2 = 200$ volume units. ($V_1 / V_2 = 1 / 2$)

Now we want $V_3$ volume units of the 60-40-mix with extras $x$, by adding $V_x$ to $V_2$. We have
$$
V_3 = V_2 + V_x = V_2 + 9\% \cdot V_3
$$

this gives 
$$
V_3 = \frac{100}{91} \cdot V_2
$$

In the example you end up with $V_3 = 219.78$ volume units of 60-40 mix with extras.

Example 2:

If we want to end up with $V_3 = 150$ volume units of the 60-40 mix with extras, then we need $V_2 = 91\% \cdot V_3 = 136.5$ volume units of the 60-40 mix and $V_x = 9\% \cdot V_3 = 13.5$ volume units of extras.

If we start with $V_1 = 50$ volume units of 90-10 mix, then we need 
$V_r = 36.9$ volume units of red paint and 
$V_b = 49.6$ volume units of blue paint.

The percentages (relative to $V_2$) are
$p_r = 27 \%$ and $p_b = 36 \%$. ($V_1 / V_2 = 0.3663$)

Answer (score 1):

First we have:

```
0.9A + m = 0.6 * 0.91T
0.1A + n = 0.4 * 0.91T
```

where A is the initial amount, m is how much red to add, n is how much blue to add and T is the final total amount. If you specify the final total you can then solve them for m and n. For the first equation:

```
m = 0.6 * 0.91T - 0.9A
```